# update random numbers for top 100 rows in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to update random numbers for top 100 rows (a field) in sql. random number should be less than 100. how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean update random numbers?

Can you please be more spacific?

Comment: You do not say how the data should be ordered and therefore you will not know which 100 records are updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In SQL 2008

```
update top (100) MyTable
set MyField = cast(cast(crypt_gen_random(1) as int) * 100.0 / 256 as int)
```

I believe the same will work in SQL 2005.

**[Edit]**

If it doesn't work in SQL 2005, you can do this:

```
update top (100) MyTable
set MyField = abs(cast(newid() as binary(6)) % 100)
```

Comment: The documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx suggests the `crypt_gen_random` function is not available in SQL Server 2005 (it's not in the "other versions" dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is ok in 2k5;

```
--add rows numbers
;with ROWS(id, fld, rownum) as 
(
    select id, fld, 
    row_number() over (order by id asc) --this order defines your "top" 
    from tablename
)
update tablename
  set fld = 1 + abs(checksum(newid())) % 100 --dont use rand() as it will give the same value
  from ROWS inner join tablename on tablename.id = ROWS.id
  where rownum between 1 and 100 --limit to 100 rows
```